# Updating Multiple Nodes in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck on the best approach to update multiple child nodes. I currently have the following method to update a single child node:

```
public static void UpdateUserInfoDatabase(string userID, string updateChild, string newChildValue)
{
    Debug.Log("UpdateUserInfoDatabase method");
    DBreference.Child("users").Child(userID).Child(updateChild).SetValueAsync(newChildValue);
}
```

How would I expand this if I would to update multiple child nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but I did the following:

```
public static void MultiUserUpdateInfoDatabase(string userID, string[] updateChild, string[] newChildValue)
{
    Debug.Log("MultiUserUpdateInfoDatabase method");
    for(int node = 0; node <= updateChild.Length; node++)
    {
        DBreference.Child("users").Child(userID).Child(updateChild[node]).SetValueAsync(newChildValue[node]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also create single `Map<String,Object>` with the *paths* and the new values for that path, and then pass that to `UpdateChildrenAsync`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your suggestion. Will look into it